# KeyError:'label' while exporting issues from github to csv

Tags: python, github, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export issues of my **public** repository and later on if successful, I'll try to pull issues from a **private** repository that I have access to.

However, when I tried the code below, it returns an error on **line 44**, `csv.writerow()` method. Error on line 48 as well which I commented.

The error I get is

*csvout.writerow([issue['id'], issue['title'], issue['label'].encode('utf-8'), issue['body'].encode('utf-8'), issue['created_at'].encode('utf-8')])
**KeyError: 'label'***

```
import csv
import requests

'''
Variables need to be modify
'''
git_user    = 'myUserName'
git_pass    = 'myPassword'
git_repo    = 'myUserName/myPublicRepoName' 
extra_param = ''
git_auth    = (git_user,git_pass)

def write_to_csv(response):
    csvfile = '%s-issues.csv' % (git_repo.replace('/', '-'))
    csvout  = csv.writer(open(csvfile, 'w'))
    csvout.writerow(('id', 'title', 'label', 'body', 'Created at'))
    for issue in r.json():
        csvout.writerow([issue['id'], issue['title'], issue['label'].encode('utf-8'), issue['body'].encode('utf-8'), issue['created_at'].encode('utf-8')]) #line 44

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/%s/issues%s' % (git_repo,extra_param), auth=git_auth);
if r.status_code == 200:
    write_to_csv(r) # line 48
else:
    raise Exception(r.status_code)
```

What could be causing this?
This is my first time to attempt to pull issues from github so I really have no idea. I researched in google but can't find the exact cause of the error.

Thank you.

Comment: The `KeyError: 'label'` shows that there is no key 'label' for issue in your response json.

Comment: @Tiny.D Thank you. What I did was I remove the issue['label'].encode('utf-8') and it worked. May I know if github doesn't return a key named 'label'? I thought at first that it was the "Label" section in github where you select "Enhancement, Bug... etc..."

Comment: No `label` but `labels`, see the documentation [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)